# ES6 global import

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

What is the best way to import some modules in all of the files of the project, so I don't have to write stuff like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Reflux from 'reflux';
import reactMixin from 'react-mixin';
```

in almost every single file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other answer covers this, but not with valid ES6, so I'm adding my own.
Make a central file to import your react components, in some central `react.js` file

```
export {default as React} from 'react';
export {default as Reflux} from 'reflux';
export {default as reactMixin} from 'react-mixin';
```

Then in the files where you need to use these three, you could do

```
import {React, Reflux, reactMixin} from './react';
```

to import all three into your component file.

Comment: Good solution. You have also the ability to import any of all (for example, you could, if you needed only that, `import {React, Reflux} from './react';`)

Comment: Will filesize increase if I import all this stuff everywhere that "doesn't need it"? Like just take everything that any file could use and import it to be safe. (`import axios from 'axios'` in a component that doesn't use requests)

Comment: There is a reason why React starting from v17 doesn’t require react.js import in every file, but it requires hook imports separately. Yes, it affects bundle size. This is why imports from index that contains bunch of exports is not a good idea… (if it didn’t affect bundle size, react wouldn’t require other stuff to be imported as well).

Answer (score 8):

Create a "base" that declares common imports, then you can import that one file.

Comment: @user860478: That file would be something like `import React from 'react'; import Reflux from 'reflux';  export {React, Reflux}` and you would use it everywhere as `import {React, Reflux} from 'path/to/base'`.